# Setting up data with constructor in derived Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, inheritance, pandas, constructor

I am trying to read in data automagically in the constructor of a derived Pandas DataFrame. The problem with the DataFrame methods not returning the derived class type can be solve by changing the _constructor property.

```
import pandas as pd

class Derived(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Derived
    def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
                 copy=False):
        print('Constructor')
        super(Derived, self).__init__(index=range(2), columns=['a', 'b'])
        data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
        self.ix[:, ['a', 'b']] = data
```

However, slicing in the instanced object call the constructor anew and setup the data again.

```
>>> d = Derived()
Constructor
>>> d[:1]
Constructor
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

I may be able to solve it with:

```
import pandas as pd

class Derived(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Derived
    def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
                 copy=False):
        print('Constructor')
        if isinstance(data, pd.core.internals.BlockManager):
            super(Derived, self).__init__(data=data, index=index, 
                                          columns=columns, dtype=dtype,
                                          copy=copy)
        else:
            super(Derived, self).__init__(index=range(2), columns=['a', 'b'])
            data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
            self.ix[:, ['a', 'b']] = data
```

This looks pretty dirty to me.

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to setup data in a Pandas DataFrame during its initialization? Would another pattern be better?

Comment: what do you mean by not returning the `Derived` type? You don't need to override the **_constructor** as far as I see here

Comment: The _constructor trick is not the issue here, but to explain: The `__init__` constructor returns the correct datatype (type(d) is 'Derived'). However, any operation on the instance object will return the parent DataFrame, rather than the derived Derived, e.g., type(d+1) is pandas.DataFrame. If you use the _constructor trick you will get type(d+1) is 'Derived'. The issue that I am asking about is how to handle data setup in the constructor. Perhaps it is a bad idea?

Comment: I see, I'm with you. May look at superclasses' **new** / **call**, or even **metaclass**, would like to see a neat solution too.